# How to integrate DataTables jQuery plug-in with this setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a HTML div that is fed a JSON output formatted as a HTML table when a function is called:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType:'json',
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    var htmlStr = '';
    htmlStr += '<table id="summary-table">'
    ... // appends table content to htmlStr
    $("#content").html(htmlStr);          
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the content, then call datatables on the table in question:

```
$("#content").html(htmlStr);
$('#summary-table').dataTable({...});
```